# Third party extension - Language

Tags: language

Is there a simple way to change the language for all modules in magento or will I have to ask the extension-maker why the language of their modules is english instead of german after the installation?

Thank you for your support!

Update: There are no csv-files in app/locale for that extension

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add your own CSV file in the de_DE folder.  Name it as Vendor_Extension.csv , or use magento default inline translations tool.

Comment: Okay, thank you! So I guess there is nothing like a dropdown menu in the admin area to choose the language?

Comment: Yes, if there is no build in translation, you need to add it somehow.  By CSV, inline translation or direct code edit (not recommended of course)

Comment: Alright, I think CSV should be the safest way because I also use git. Thank you very much!